# Rational points over completions of a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically irreducible $k$-variety over a number field $k$.
I do not assume that $X$ has a $k$-point.
Is it true that $X$ has $k_v$-points for almost all places $v$ of $k$?

Comment: This ought to be the Lang-Weil estimate to get points over almost all residue fields, then Hensel's lemma. So if the reductions are almost all smooth, where is the obstruction?

Comment: The reductions are almost all smooth if $X$ is smooth, basically because singularity means that some matrix of partial derivatives has zero det, but this can only happen mod $p$ for finitely many $p$.

Note that you do need geom irred though, because e.g. the spectrum of a number field $L$ Galois over $k$ doesn't have $k_v$-points when $v$ doesn't split.


Comment: @Charles: doesn't Lang-Weil say something about points over bigger and bigger finite fields of the same characteristic? Does it also work if you're changing the characteristic?

Comment: @Kevin: Lang-Weil does apply but, if you are bothered by it, apply Deligne instead.

Comment: @Felipe Voloch: sorry but, may I ask which result of Deligne? Thanks.

Comment: @all: I think applying Deligne (presumably this means his proof of the Riemann hypothesis for varieties over finite fields) is big overkill here.  See my answer below.

Comment: @shenghao: What Pete said. @Pete: I was kidding. 

Comment: @Kevin: Yes Lang-Weil applies uniformly: for any $n$, $d$ and $D$, there exists a real number $C(n,d,D)$ such that if $X$ is geometrically integral, of dimension $d$, and defined by polynomials of degree $D$ in the affine space $A^n$ over a finite field $k$ with $q$ elements, then $|\# X(k)-q^d|\leq C(n,d,D) q^{d-1/2}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without loss of generality $X$ is affine, so embed it in projective space and apply the Bertini Theorem to conclude that $X$ contains a smooth, geometrically integral affine curve $C^{\circ}$ missing $N$ points from its projective completion $C$.  Such a guy will remain smooth modulo $v$ for almost all places of $v$ -- this follows immediately from the Jacobian condition -- and now you are reduced to Weil's theorem: you have a family of smooth affine curves $C^{\circ}$ over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_v$ of fixed genus and missing $N_v \leq N$ points from its projective completion (in fact $N_v = N$ for sufficiently large $v$).  Now the Weil bounds tell you that the number of $\mathbb{F}_v$-rational points goes to infinity with $\# \mathbb{F}_v$.  Finally, apply Hensel's Lemma.

Comment: You do realize that the proof of Lang-Weil is to fiber by hyperplane sections and induct on dimension from the case of curves...

Comment: @Felipe: Honestly?  No, I didn't realize that.  But maybe I saw it before, grasped the idea, and forgot where it came from.